# Python: Incomplete URL Regex Output

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, url

I have created a "lite" URL regex. That means it may not detect all URLs. I created it with the aim of covering simple urls.

```
#! python3
# urls.py - Detecting urls that begin with http:// or https://

import re

urlRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (http://|https://)+          # the http(s) part of the url
    (w{3}\.)?              # the world-wide-web part
    ([a-z0-9-])+            # the domain name
    (\.[a-z]{2,4})?        # sub level domain
    (\.[a-z]{2,4})        # top level domain
    (/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])* # extension i.e paths
)''', re.VERBOSE)
test = urlRegex.search('https://www.facebook.com/user_2033')
```

The output of `test.groups()` was this

```
('https://www.facebook.com/user_2033', 'https://', 'www.', 'k', None, '.com', '/u')
[Finished in 0.058s]
```

After numerous attempts, I'm unable to display the complete website name and extension i.e `'facebook' not 'k'`. Any help without completely changing my own code would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(PATTERN)*` or `(PATTERN)+` will capture the last matched character only. It should be `(PATTERN*)` or `(PATTERN+)` to capture all characters.

---

```
([a-z0-9-])+          # the domain name
```

should be replaced with:

```
([a-z0-9-]+)          # the domain name
```

Same for the last part:

```
(/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|])* # extension i.e paths

(/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]*) # extension i.e paths
```

---

output:

```
('https://www.facebook.com/user_2033', 'https://', 's', 'www.',
 'facebook', None, '.com', '/user_2033')
```

---

BTW, you can use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) (Python 3) / [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) (Python 2) instead of regular expression:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse('https://www.facebook.com/user_2033')
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.facebook.com',
            path='/user_2033', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: @ITJ, I added explanation at the top of the answer.

Comment: @ITJ, I justed add alternative way to parse the url (using urllib.parse.urlparse)

Answer (score 0):

i've use the following regex to simply verify URL:

```
((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z]){2,6}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])*
```